# viewDidAppear() not being called when home button is pressed then launched again

Tags: swift, animation, viewdidload

I notice that `viewDidAppear` is not being called when the home screen is pressed and then launched again. This is why my animation stop working after I press the home button and then launch my app again. Is there any way to fix this?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    print("View did appear is launched")
    tapToPlayLabel.startBlink()
    settingsButton.startRotating()
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `viewDidLoad` to be called just because you pressed the Home button?

Comment: @Lawliet `viewWillApear ` will be triggered if you go back to this view controller though `dismiss` or `pop`. It's not triggered when the app goes to foreground.

Comment: Yeah, he said when he clicked on home button. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, register on notification center to detect app entering foreground.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToForeground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

Then do whatever animation you want in the handler function

```
func appMovedToForeground() {
    tapToPlayLabel.startBlink()
    settingsButton.startRotating()
}
```

Comment: You can make that a bit shorter by dropping `Notification.Name` and just using `.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: @Fangming Ning where do I put the first code? In the viewDidLoad?

Comment: The code works but my animation still doesn't run. I think there's something wrong with my animation.

Comment: @BlueB.Yup. That is the set up code and should happen only once

Comment: @BlueB. Sure. Please mark this question as answered if it helps you. For your animation problem, post a new question if you cannot figure it out and we will be happy to help you

Comment: Ok, I marked this question as answered. I will make a new post about the animation problem. Can you take a look when I'm done posting it? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @BlueB. Sure. Just tag swift. There are also other brillient people out there and are willing to help you too :)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I am done posting the animation problem.